# How to construct a harmonic mapping

Tags: visualization

How to construct a harmonic mapping on the complex plane using the method of "Shear Construction"?

Comment: What have you tried?  And what's this have to do with the *Mathematica* programming language???

Comment: I build harmonic mappings on the complex plane. The method I'm using is "Shear Construction" (J. CLUNIE and T. SHEIL-SMALL). I tried writing the code in Wolphram Mathematica, but I do not get to build a unit disk on which the mapping is created, although the mapping itself is created.